# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in 3d array

Tags: javascript

Following is my Code:

```
        var i,j;
        var period = 5;
        var sec = new Array(new Array(new Array()));
        for(i=0;i<6;i++){
            for(j=1;j<period;j++){  
                sec[j][i][j] = j;
                console.log("SEC: "+j+i+j+" = "+sec[j][i][j]);
                console.log('/n');
            }
        }
```

When I execute the above code I get cannot read property '0' of undefined at sec[j][i][j] assignment.
I don't understand the reason behind it..
It would be great if you guys can help me on this. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because sec[1][0][1] is undefined, you need to push an array every time

```js
        var i,j, period = 6;
        var sec = [];
        for(i=0;i<6;i++){
            for(j=1;j<period;j++){
                sec[j] = [];
                sec[j][i] = [];
                sec[j][i][j] = j;
                console.log("SEC: "+j+i+j+" = "+sec[j][i][j]);
                console.log('/n');
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var sec = new Array(new Array(new Array()));
```

Doesn't do what you think it does. Try to allocate the inner arrays when needed like this instead

```
var i, j;
var period = 5;
var sec = [];
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j < period; j++) {
    sec[j] = sec[j] || [];
    sec[j][i] = sec[j][i] || [];
    sec[j][i][j] = j;
    console.log("SEC: " + j + i + j + " = " + sec[j][i][j]);
    console.log('\n');
  }
}
```

Also, /n prints '/n' not a new line which is \n

Answer (score 0):

Although you have declared array as 3D array, JavaScript do not allocate the memory to it.

So being 3D array sec[0] is undefined.

Comment: so if I am not using sec[0] at all how do I proceed?

Comment: Refer @peter solution